# Vaadin how to get the Spring java object instance as a singleton behaviour

Tags: java, spring, vaadin7

In our Project we are using the Vaadin and Spring code.Please check the below vaadin class.

1)In our project we have the 3 menu tabs
  a)TR Page
  b)Execution Page
  c)Administration Page 
These 3 classes are extending the BaseView Class as mentioned below.

2)But the problem is in the below class,Search panel object is creating no.of times when we click on tr,execution and administration menu tabs.

## Need:

What i need is,In the below code the search panel object should be create only once and when we click on the different menu pages and same instance should be used for all the menu tabs.

## Note:

In our project we are using the AppConfig.java class is using for configuring the beans.

## BaseView Class:

```
public abstract class BaseView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

private SearchPanel searchPanel;


//private SearchVO searchVO ;
private SearchVO searchVO = new SearchVO();

public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    removeAllComponents();
    setSizeFull();
    this.setHeight("100%");
    if (UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().getState().equals("tr") || UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().getState().equals("ep") ||
            UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().getState().equals("db")) {
        searchPanel = new SearchPanel(this);
    }
    }
```

## ExecutionPlan extends Base View Class:

```
public class ExecutionPlanListView extends BaseView {

@Autowired
ExecutionPlanDelegate executionPlanDelegate;

@Override
public Component getMainContent(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    //Some Code

}
```

}

## TR extends Base View Class:

```
public class TR extends BaseView {

@Autowired
ExecutionPlanDelegate executionPlanDelegate;

@Override
public Component getMainContent(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    //Some Code

}
```

}

## Administration extends Base View Class:

```
public class Administration extends BaseView {

@Autowired
ExecutionPlanDelegate executionPlanDelegate;

@Override
public Component getMainContent(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
    //Some Code

}
```

}